# Is the vector $v_{1}$ in the linear subspace $\text{ span}\left\{v_{2}\right\} + V$ (trying to understand the task)?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> We are in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and have the vectors
>
> $$v_{1}=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\  1\\  0  \end{pmatrix}, v_{2}=
> \begin{pmatrix} 1\\  0\\  1  \end{pmatrix}$$ and the linear subspace
>   $$V= \left\{\begin{pmatrix} a\\  b\\  c  \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{3}:a-3b+c=0\right\}$$
>
> Is the vector $v_{1}$ in the linear subspace $\text{
> span}\left\{v_{2}\right\} + V$?

This is a task from an old exam and I'm trying to understand it.

How would you write $\text {span}\left\{v_{2}\right\}$? How would you write the complete thing $\text{
span}\left\{v_{2}\right\} + V$?

I think if I know these, maybe I can solve the task but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asked to solve:

$v_1 = \alpha v_2+ V \Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 1\\  1\\  0  \end{pmatrix} = \alpha \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1\\  0\\  1  \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} a\\  b\\  c  \end{pmatrix}$

This expression gives you the following system of linear equations:

\begin{array}{ccl}
     a-3b+c = 0 \\
     \alpha + a = 1 \\
     b = 1 \\
     \alpha + c = 0
   \end{array}

With solution $a=2,b=1,c=1,\alpha=-1$

Comment: Does that mean the vector $v_{1}$ isn't a linear subspace because not all the equations are solvable? Or is the reasoning wrong now?

Comment: @cnmesr The system of equations has solution so you can express $v_1$ as a combination of $\alpha v_2 + V$. That means that $v_1$ is in the linear subspace. Just plug in the values of $a,b,c,\alpha$ in the above expression and you will end up with $v_1$

Comment: Ahhh now I see, I thought we had to check the linear equations if they are correct. Because two of them don't work if we put the solutions in. But this doesn't seem to be important here, right? As example, first equation gives, if solutions inserted: $2-3-1=0 \Leftrightarrow -2=0$

Comment: I had a typo in $c$ sorry. $c=1$ I've fixed it now. Now if you plug in the values you will end up with $v_1$.

Comment: Just one more question if you are still around :P, what if we had $\text{ span}\left\{v_{1},v_{2}\right\}$ instead? Would this equal this: $$\alpha \cdot v_{1} + \beta \cdot v_{2}$$?

Comment: Yes. The span represents the set of all linear combination given a set of vectors, this is, any combination of $\alpha \cdot v_1 + \beta\cdot v_2$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition span$(v_2) = \{kv_2 \, | \, k \in \mathbb{R} \}$ is just scalar multiples of $v_2$. And the sum is just $$\text{span}(v_2)+V=\{ a + b \, | \, a \in \text{span}( v_2 ), \, b \in V  \}$$

So the question is: can the vector $v_1$ be represented as a sum of two vectors where one is from $V$ and the other is a scalar multiple of $v_2$.